# JMH Benchmark Metrics Evaluation

Tags: java, benchmarking

I'm currently attempting to learn some basic JVM optimization techniques using [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/).

I created the following bench to compare mid-index insertion performance between `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`.

How exactly do I measure `score` vs `error` in the final results?

The documentation states:

> Your benchmarks should be peer-reviewed

I'm not quite sure how to validate the results, so I'm asking for a review of the following implementation to determine whether my workflow is correct. Any advice would be appreciated as I don't have much experience in performance evaluation techniques.

```
public class ListBench {

    static List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    static List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();

    private static int COUNT = 100;

    static {
        arrayList.add( 0 );
        linkedList.add( 0 );
    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode( Mode.Throughput )
    public static void arrayListBench() {

        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            arrayList.add( mid( arrayList.size() ), i + 1 );
        }

    }

    @Benchmark
    @BenchmarkMode( Mode.Throughput )
    public static void linkedListBench() {

        for(int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            linkedList.add( mid( linkedList.size() ), i + 1 );
        }
    }

    public static int mid( int n ) {
        return n / 2;
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws RunnerException {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include( ListBench.class.getSimpleName() )
            .warmupIterations( 10)
            .measurementIterations( 10 )
            .forks( 1 )
            .build();

        new Runner( opt ).run();
    }

}
```

**Init Params** 
`java -jar target/benchmarks.jar ListBench -wi 10 -i 10 -f 1`

**Results**

> ```
> # JMH 1.10-SNAPSHOT (released today)
> # VM invoker: c:\Java\jdk_8\jre\bin\java.exe
> # VM options: <none>
> # Warmup: 10 iterations, 1 s each
> # Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
> # Timeout: 10 min per iteration
> # Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
> # Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
> # Benchmark: com.beckett.ListBench.arrayListBench
>
> # Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:00:40
> # Fork: 1 of 1
> # Warmup Iteration   1: 1578.361 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   2: 609.785 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   3: 431.937 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   4: 354.311 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   5: 290.205 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   6: 286.704 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   7: 273.980 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   8: 256.947 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   9: 241.936 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration  10: 216.881 ops/s
> Iteration   1: 218.604 ops/s
> Iteration   2: 208.873 ops/s
> Iteration   3: 200.316 ops/s
> Iteration   4: 192.754 ops/s
> Iteration   5: 167.496 ops/s
> Iteration   6: 173.361 ops/s
> Iteration   7: 167.943 ops/s
> Iteration   8: 163.542 ops/s
> Iteration   9: 158.993 ops/s
> Iteration  10: 144.436 ops/s
>
>
> Result "arrayListBench":
>   179.632 ±(99.9%) 36.413 ops/s [Average]
>   (min, avg, max) = (144.436, 179.632, 218.604), stdev = 24.085
>   CI (99.9%): [143.219, 216.044] (assumes normal distribution)
>
>
> # JMH 1.10-SNAPSHOT (released today)
> # VM invoker: c:\Java\jdk_8\jre\bin\java.exe
> # VM options: <none>
> # Warmup: 10 iterations, 1 s each
> # Measurement: 10 iterations, 1 s each
> # Timeout: 10 min per iteration
> # Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
> # Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
> # Benchmark: com.beckett.ListBench.linkedListBench
>
> # Run progress: 50.00% complete, ETA 00:00:20
> # Fork: 1 of 1
> # Warmup Iteration   1: 446.279 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   2: 183.674 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   3: 140.986 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   4: 118.704 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   5: 100.247 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   6: 94.524 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   7: 86.703 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   8: 80.523 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration   9: 75.306 ops/s
> # Warmup Iteration  10: 68.613 ops/s
> Iteration   1: 67.402 ops/s
> Iteration   2: 64.286 ops/s
> Iteration   3: 61.578 ops/s
> Iteration   4: 58.948 ops/s
> Iteration   5: 54.654 ops/s
> Iteration   6: 55.136 ops/s
> Iteration   7: 53.127 ops/s
> Iteration   8: 51.460 ops/s
> Iteration   9: 50.100 ops/s
> Iteration  10: 46.219 ops/s
>
>
> Result "linkedListBench":
>   56.291 ±(99.9%) 10.073 ops/s [Average]
>   (min, avg, max) = (46.219, 56.291, 67.402), stdev = 6.663
>   CI (99.9%): [46.218, 66.364] (assumes normal distribution)
>
>
> # Run complete. Total time: 00:00:40
>
> Benchmark                   Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
> ListBench.arrayListBench   thrpt   10  179.632 ± 36.413  ops/s
> ListBench.linkedListBench  thrpt   10   56.291 ± 10.073  ops/s
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Important things:

1. Have you read [JMH Samples](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/tip/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/)?
2. Your benchmark does not
   have steady state. You can actually see that with diminishing
   performance iteration-to-iteration, and a large score error at the
   end. Measuring non-steady state benchmarks [is a tricky
   business.](http://shipilev.net/blog/2014/nanotrusting-nanotime/#_steady_state_considerations)
3. Looping in benchmarks is generally discouraged, because loop
   unrolling optimizations, and subsequent code transformations may
   affect the benchmarks in unpredictable ways. See
   [JMHSample_11_Loops](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/16f9d77c2233/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_11_Loops.java) and [JMHSample_34_SafeLooping](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/16f9d77c2233/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_34_SafeLooping.java).
4. Single fork is almost never enough. Run-to-run variance is a very frequent contender in performance results.
5. The last, but not the least, you have to ***analyze*** benchmarks, not just running them. Use profilers to understand what is going on, wriggle experimental setup to see if it reacts to changes similar to your mental model, etc.

Stylistic things (or, things that make JMH tests more idiomatic, and therefore quickly understandable):

1. `static`-s are not handy for storing states, especially if the next thing you try is testing with multiple threads. Use `@Setup` methods instead. See [JMHSample_05_StateFixtures](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/16f9d77c2233/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_05_StateFixtures.java).
2. `static` constants are bad substitutes for `@Param`. See [JMHSample_27_Params](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/16f9d77c2233/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_27_Params.java).
3. You don't need `main()` method to run benchmarks. In fact, running with uberjar is more reliable, as every sample links the caveats from JMH page:

   > Running benchmarks from the IDE is generally not recommended due to
   >   generally uncontrolled environment in which the benchmarks run.
4. You don't also need to build JMH to make benchmark runs (I see you are using `1.10-SNAPSHOT`). All recent artifacts are available from Maven Central, and [JMH page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) has a one-liner to generate the benchmark project from the archetype.

Comment: Thanks Aleksey ~ I developed my implementation after a cursory review of the JMH Samples and came to a similar conclusion as you stated in item 3... However, I'm still a bit uncertain how to refactor my bench to work correctly for this use case.... I'll spend more time going through the samples.

Answer (score 5):

By using both to be measured classes

```
static List<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

static List<Integer> linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
```

you're preventing Class Hierarchy Analysis (CHA). If the JVM could determine that there's just a single implementation of `List`, it could devirtualize all calls to `List` methods(*). As both `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` are used a lot, you're safe to ignore this problem, but with other classes [it's very important](https://github.com/google/guava/issues/1268). So you should rewrite the initialization to instantiate only the relevant class. As a bonus, you'd need a single `@Benchmark` only.

---

```
Benchmark                   Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
ListBench.arrayListBench   thrpt   10  179.632 ± 36.413  ops/s
ListBench.linkedListBench  thrpt   10   56.291 ± 10.073  ops/s
```

The score `56±10` has a nearly 20% error, which is a lot. No idea what could be done to improve it (except for increasing the number of iterations which helps a bit, but costs a lot of time).

However, the results are sufficiently clear: `LinkedList` is the loser as it should be(**). Because of `56+10` being (much) less than `180-36` and because of the high confidence level `99.9%` you can be pretty sure.

(*) If later another implementation gets loaded, all methods using CHA have to be deoptimized (and recompiled again). But all class loading happens at safepoints, so there's no runtime cost for this check.

(**) [Joshua Bloch admitted](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248) that it was a mistake to include it in the JVM 20 years ago. With deeper memory hierarchies, it's becoming more and more unusable.

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the Joshua Bloch comment?  (I believe it, but I think it is a good idea to add a secondary reference.)

Comment: @kevinarpe I could find just a tweet saying "Does anyone actually use LinkedList?  I wrote it, and I never use it.".